# LibGDX . draw multiline text

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to write a big text using BitmapFont in libGDX . But it shows on one line and the user can see only the first part of the text . How can I make that bitmapFont made new line automatically and show whole text on the screen ?

Comment: So basically you are looking for a "Word wrap" option.

Comment: yes, something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [BitmapFont.drawWrapped](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html#drawWrapped-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch-java.lang.CharSequence-float-float-float-).

```
public BitmapFont.TextBounds drawWrapped(Batch batch,
                                     java.lang.CharSequence str,
                                     float x,
                                     float y,
                                     float wrapWidth)
```

All you need to do is set the `wrapWidth` variable as the maximum length of the line. In your case, this works better than `BitmapFont.drawMultiLine` because it automatically wraps rather than solely responding to `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

**Write multiline text in LibGdx**

To write a multiline text with bitmapFont just use this following code-

```
String completeText= "In this text there are multi lines\n.To write this race in your game 
                     \n you have to write in proper manner.
                     \nYou have to make the text look better .";

 font.drawMultiLine(
            batch,
            completeText,
             x,y,width,heigth, HAlignment.LEFT);
```

**Isn't is simple to write a multiline text.**